# How to get file path on Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to get file path on Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker? I am getting file name and byteData but how to get file path? Here is my code-

```
try
            {
                FileData filedata = new FileData();
                var crossFileData = CrossFilePicker.Current;
                filedata = await crossFileData.PickFile();
                byte[] data = filedata.DataArray;
                string name = filedata.FileName;
                AtttchFileName.Text = name;
                if(AtttchFileName.Text==null)
                {
                    DoneAttachment.IsEnabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    DoneAttachment.IsEnabled = true;
                }
                foreach (byte b in filedata.DataArray)
                {
                    string attachment = b.ToString();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string msg = ex.Message;
            }
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If a path, or a file Uri, is available, it is assigned to the `FileData.FilePath` property:

```
filedata = await crossFileData.PickFile();
var filePath = filedata.FilePath;
```

re: [Plugin.FilePicker.Abstractions/FileData.cs#L67](https://github.com/Studyxnet/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows/blob/51aac06f38c4943e9893fc67df07fac887cd6fe3/FilePicker/FilePicker/Plugin.FilePicker.Abstractions/FileData.cs#L67)

Comment: filedata.FilePath not found only i can find FileName,My FilePicker version is 1.1.0

Comment: @HarshitaGhosh That nuget package is outdated compared to the source code. Clone the project and compile it from source as the author never published those changes.

Comment: Can you give a suggestion? which plugin i can use for picking file from storage device in xamarin.forms

Comment: @HarshitaGhosh ? Why not download the source and compile it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [FilePicker](https://github.com/jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows) for Xamarin, since it has file path like you need.

```
FileData filedata = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
string filepath = filedata.FilePath;
```

Nuget package for it is [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker/1.2.1).